# Why don't we add special Holiday sections to Al Hamichya on Purim or Chanukah?

Tags: blessing, halacha-theory

Much like Birkat Hamazon, there are special Holiday sections added to Al Hamichya on all of the Yom Tov days that do not involve fasting. Unlike Birkhat Hamazon, however, Purim and Chanukah are not acknowledged in the holiday section of this after-bracha. Do we know why that is so?

Comment: The Artscroll Simchat Yehoshua siddur series has the Chanukah and Purim additions in the Birkhat Hamazon but omits them in Al Hamichya. Aish HaTorah's Jewish Pathways editions also follow this practice.

Comment: Hm? Al Hamichya/Haetz/Hagefen is Mein Shalosh